# How to properly synchronise a transaction?

Tags: java, synchronization

What is a proper synchronisation in the following situation?

```java
public class Product {

    private int amountAvailable;
    private User seller; 

    public int subtractFromAmountAvailable(int amount) {
        amountAvailable = amountAvailable - amount;
        return amountAvailable;
    }
}

public class User {

    private int account;

    public int depositToAccount(int amount) {
        deposit = deposit + amount;
        return deposit;
    }

    public int withdrawFromAccount(int amount) {
        deposit = deposit - amount;
        return deposit;
    }
}
```

If a user buys a product, the amount of money has to be transferred to the seller's account and the product's amountAvailable field has to be updated. What is a proper way of synchronising this transaction?

Would the following work?

```java
public class Transaction {
       
    public void performTransaction(User buyer, Product product, int amount) {
           int totalCost = product.getCost() * amount;
 
            synchronized (this) {
                product.subtractFromAmountAvailable(amount);
                product.getSeller().depositToAccount(totalCost);
                buyer.withdrawFromAccount(totalCost);
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you are talking about is a standard feature for enterprise system. In Java, the system is the Java Transaction API (https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/transactions002.html#:~:text=In%20a%20Java%20EE%20application,a%20commit%20or%20a%20rollback.) it involves creating a transaction on a database which on failure can be rolled back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No for several reasons.

When you use synchronized on an instance method the calling thread acquires a lock on the instance the method is called on.

Locking matters only if all the different threads involved  are using the same lock. In your example how would different threads know to use the same transaction object?

There is a bigger issue. applications need to be able to scale horizontally, there will be multiple jvms involved and no object lock like this will be getting shared across jvms anyway.

It would make more sense to use database row level locking. Use a transaction, Select the rows you want to change with lock. Then you can update them and no other process can interfere until the transaction is completed.  That way all the application instances have a shared lock.